# linked reports in sharepoint

Tags: sharepoint, reporting-services

On sharepoint server we can publish out SSRS reports. And it is fine.

We are moving our SSRS reports from reporting services to sharepoint. But I have some linked reports. After a little research, I've found that "linked reports are not supported".
[here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb326290.aspx)

Is there any way to implement "linked reports" on sharepoint.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What do you want to hear... it is not supported by Microsoft. And when migrating reports to Reporting Services SharePoint integrated mode you will have several annoyances to deal with (this is one of them).

Since the Reporting Services Instance is configured to run in SharePoint integrated mode you also won't have any luck running the report outside of SharePoint instead of nicely integrated, I reckon. Your only chance might be to set up another Reporting Service instance and have those reports with linked reports run off of that, it will be a hassle though - maybe you're better off re-designing your reports.

Answer (score 0):

Wrong. It's just called something different. Click on "View Properties", then in the ribbon "Manage Copies". You can do it in there. Below is a site that gives a visual. I hope this helps someone, because we'v struggled with it for 3 months and just now stumbled on how to do it.

http://www.mssharepointtips.com/tip.asp?id=1127&page=2

Comment: SharePoint document "copies" are not the same thing as Linked Reports in SSRS Native Mode. They can be used to simulate some of the functionality but not all of it.